# Pascal triangle path summation via fold with binomial expansion - based accumulator

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, non-deterministic, pascals-triangle

**SPOILER**: This is [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net) problem #18. **READ AT YOUR OWN RISK**

The problem is to find the "maximal sum" of all the non-deterministic paths from the top of a pascal triangle going strictly downward to the bottom. I am trying to calculate the sums by doing a fold over the rows of the triangle.

Here is the input string, and some basic preparations:

```
inputLines = ["75",
              "95 64",
              "17 47 82",
              "18 35 87 10",
              "20 04 82 47 65",
              "19 01 23 75 03 34",
              "88 02 77 73 07 63 67",
              "99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92",
              "41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33",
              "41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29",
              "53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14",
              "70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57",
              "91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48",
              "63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31",
              "04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23"]

input = map (map (read ::String ->Integer) . words) inputLines

prepareElems :: [[Integer]] -> [[Elem Integer]]
prepareElems = map mkElemsFromTri
```

There are two ideas here - having the row of a tree, and having a row of the triangle. I didn't do very much type-level abstraction, but that should not matter as much. The idea is that every row in the triangle is a "parallel enumeration" of binomials across it's length (ie: `[(4,0), (3,1), (2,2), ... (0,4)]`), and every row of the tree get's "copy-forked" before the labelled triangle row is applied to the tree's row, making sure that the non-determinism's integrity is retained at each opportunity to fork. Here is what my technique looks like:

```
data BiLabel = BiLabel Integer Integer
  deriving (Show, Eq)

leftLabel (BiLabel x _) = x
rightLabel (BiLabel _ y) = y

parEnumBiLabel :: Integer -> [BiLabel]
parEnumBiLabel n = map ( \x ->BiLabel x $ (n-1)-x ) [0..(n-1)]


forkBiLabel :: BiLabel -> (BiLabel, BiLabel)
forkBiLabel (BiLabel x y) = (BiLabel (x+1) y,BiLabel x (y+1))

data Elem a = Elem {label :: BiLabel, element :: a}
  deriving (Show, Eq)

forkElem :: Elem a -> [Elem a]
forkElem (Elem l a) = [Elem left a,Elem right a]
  where
    (left,right) = forkBiLabel l

-- Does a binomial expansion, but cloning the elements and making new labels
cloneNextLevel :: [Elem Integer] -> [Elem Integer]
cloneNextLevel = concatMap forkElem
```

My issue is that the code works for *one* row of input, but is failing when folding over *multiple* rows. My gut is telling me that my "copy-fork" technique is creating new labels before my `overElems` function can apply *via* the labels it expects to have access to. Here are my main functions:

```
-- this applys a 1-ary function to all Elems of a list that match the label
onLabel :: (a -> a) -> BiLabel -> [Elem a] -> [Elem a]
onLabel f (BiLabel la lb) (x:xs) | label x == BiLabel la lb = processHead : processTail
                                 | otherwise = x : processTail
   where
    processHead = Elem (BiLabel la lb) $ f (element x)
    processTail = onLabel f (BiLabel la lb) xs 
onLabel _ _ [] = []


-- this _tries_ to do the equivalent of `onLabel`, but over lists and 2-ary functions
overElems :: (a -> a -> a) -> [Elem a] -> [Elem a] -> [Elem a]
overElems f (x:xs) ys = overElems f xs ( onLabel (f $ element x) (label x) ys )
overElems _ [] ys = ys


-- This starts with the first element of `input` as an accumulator, just because
-- then I won't have to copy it over as part of the fold, and can simply 
-- `cloneNextLevel` before I process it with `overElems`.
calculate :: [[Elem Integer]] -> [Elem Integer]
calculate = foldr (\z acc -> overElems (+) z (cloneNextLevel acc)) [Elem (BiLabel 0 0) (head $ head input)]
```

The strange thing is that folding over one row **works**, but folding over multiple fails to do apply the higher order function, yet still expands the result to the correct size. Here are a couple example inputs:

```
\> calculate $ prepareElems [[2,3]]

[Elem {label = BiLabel 1 0, element = 78},Elem {label = BiLabel 0 1, element = 77}]
-- that's correct, because the first element of the tree is 75

\> calculate $ prepareElems [[2,3],[10,20,30]]

[Elem {label = BiLabel 2 0, element = 75},Elem {label = BiLabel 1 1, element = 75},
Elem {label = BiLabel 1 1, element = 75},Elem {label = BiLabel 0 2, element = 75}]
-- this is the correct size and labeling, but not the right contents.
```

Would lazyness in my list processing cause this? My sense is that label enumeration is happening before `overWith` has a chance to apply the function via labels. Here is a [full page](http://lpaste.net/110785) of my code, too.

Comment: This is really complex. You'll get more responses if you simplify your question and provide only minimal examples.

Comment: Okay, I'll see if I can isolate the issue to a second-handed fold for list processing, or something along those lines. Thank you!

Comment: Aha! So I needed a `foldl` instead of a `foldr`. I still don't know _exactly_ why, but I think it has to do with how foldr accumulates expressions vs. how foldl does, and how my functions expect to be treated.

Comment: @AthanClark: If you just post that as a separate question (ie why does foldl work in this simple example but foldr doesn't), you might get a good explanation. Right now, there's too much code and noise for me to easily figure this out.